# SSH freezes the whole computer when logging in

Tags: debian, ssh, freeze

I am using a Debian wheezy mainly to play music and browse web as a shared computer. Problem is that all SSH connections freeze the computer for a moment when initiated. To be clear: all these SSH connections work normally from any other computer, so the problem is more likely on the client sending the requests than on the server receiving it. 
What I see when I initiate an SSH connection:

- CPU usage goes up to 100% (according to the small display on taskbar)
- All applications freeze e.g. music stops playing and top command on terminal freezes
- After an about minute, I finally get the password prompt to login and at that point the freeze is over and all starts to work normally (the example login below was just login and logout immediately to get an approximation of the time used)

Other things I have looked into:

- I can ping the servers I am connecting to
- SFTP does not work either
- All other connections work seemingly fine

Behind the link is more information about the process (I changed the usernames and computer names). Is there something I am missing about what could be causing this problem?

http://pastebin.com/eScXsL2p

Comment: what kind of CPU does the music-playing server have?  what kind and size of key does the ssh client have?  it may be an underpowered CPU trying to deal with an oversized key (not that oversized keys are a bad thing, generally....the bigger, the safer as a general rule.  as long as there's sufficient CPU power to handle them in a reasonable time).

Comment: I don't have to information just now, but I am quite confident that the CPU is powerful enough as the computer has worked fine for two years and only now the problems have emerged. I have not made any big updates or other big changes lately either... I was thinking that maybe there is a problem with big mounted shares from other computers, but removing them didn't help...